# How to change color of getters and setters in the android studio?

Tags: colors, getter-setter

I have recently discovered Lombok which, among other things, makes getters and setters generate automatically and invisibly. Previously I would use fields which have a nice color pink in the IDE. Even though I am semantically correct I still miss being able to see my setters and getters as pink. I know I can configure the color of fields and methods in Android Studio but how can I only change the color of getters and setters? I am using Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 3

Thank you very much for your time.